# pytorch with CIFAR-100

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform=transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5),(0.5))])

trainset=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./dataset',train=True,
                                  download=True,transform=transform)

trainloader=torch.utils.data.CIFAR100(trainset,batch_size=4,shuffle=True)

testset=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./dataset',train=False,
                                 download=True,transform=transform)

testloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset,batch_size=4,shuffle=False)

classes=('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

the error message written as below
module 'torch.utils.data' has no attribute 'CIFAR100'

when I use torch.utils.data with cifar-10, it worked
but it doesn't work with cifar-100
could u plz let me know why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your trainloader line, you have to pass the trainset to `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. Replace this line with,

```
trainloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset,batch_size=4,shuffle=True)
```